# Play Framework: "too many connections" database error

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, jooq

Play Framework 2.6, Postgresql. Jooq as db access library.

When running test, I'm getting

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients
>   already

Here is a helper class which provides jooq's dsl context:

```
@Singleton
class Db @Inject() (val db: Database, system: ActorSystem) {

  val databaseContext: ExecutionContext = system.dispatchers.lookup("contexts.database")

  def query[A](block: DSLContext => A): Future[A] = Future {
    db.withConnection { connection: Connection =>
      val dsl = DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.POSTGRES_9_4)
      block(dsl)
    }
  }(databaseContext)

  def withTransaction[A](block: DSLContext => A): Future[A] = Future {
    db.withTransaction { connection: Connection =>
      val dsl: DSLContext = DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.POSTGRES_9_4)
      block(dsl)
    }
  }(databaseContext)
}
```

I use this helper class in repositories like this:

```
db.query { dsl =>
      val records = dsl
        .selectFrom(USERS)
        .where(...)
        ...  
      }
    }
```

**application.conf**

```
db.default.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres?user=postgres"

    ...
contexts { 
    database {
        executor = "thread-pool-executor"
        throughput = 1
        thread-pool-executor {
          fixed-pool-size = 9
        }
    }
}
...
```

**build.sbt**

```
...
libraryDependencies += jdbc
libraryDependencies += "org.jooq" % "jooq" % "3.10.5"
libraryDependencies += "org.jooq" % "jooq-codegen-maven" % "3.10.5"
libraryDependencies += "org.jooq" % "jooq-meta" % "3.10.5"
libraryDependencies += "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.1.4"
...
```

And base trait for all my tests for any case:

```
class BaseFeatureSpec extends FeatureSpec
  with GivenWhenThen
  with GuiceOneServerPerSuite
  with Matchers
  with WsScalaTestClient
  with BeforeAndAfterEach
  with MockitoSugar {

  override def fakeApplication(): Application =
    new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
      .overrides(bind[EmailService].to(classOf[EmailServiceStub]))
      .build()

  def config: Configuration = fakeApplication().configuration
  def actorSystem: ActorSystem = fakeApplication().actorSystem

  val db: Db = app.injector.instanceOf[Db]

  val wsClient: WSClient = app.injector.instanceOf[WSClient]
  val myPublicAddress = s"localhost:$port"

  private val injector = fakeApplication().injector

  def truncateDbOnEachRun = true

  override protected def beforeEach(): Unit = {
    if (truncateDbOnEachRun) {
      truncateDb
    }
  }

   protected def truncateDb = {
    await(db.withTransaction { dsl =>
      ... truncate all dbs...
    })
  }
}
```

max_connections of my postgresql instance is 100.

What I noticed is that when running test, I see that pool is created multiple times almost before each test:

```
[info] application - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
[info] application - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
[info] application - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
[info] application - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
```

And after I'm getting `too many connections` error.

Please help.

Comment: Which part of the app do you want to test?

Comment: I'm testing whole application (integration test with real web server), each test tests http endpoints which in turn call all layers down to db. Why?

Comment: I don't see any issue with your code on the jOOQ side, so I'm supposing the problem is more related to how you configured that datasource...

Answer (score 0):

Look like you use a dispatcher with default type, try to add type = PinnedDispatcher, which is used for io type dispatcher, as follow.

```
thread-pool-executor {
  ...
  type = PinnedDispatcher
}
```

And you can find details from 
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/dispatchers.html

Answer (score 0):

I'v found the issue:

```
override def fakeApplication(): Application =
    new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
      .overrides(bind[EmailService].to(classOf[EmailServiceStub]))
      .build()
```

Creates new application instance (because it is method) each time I access to it like `app.injector.instanceOf[Db]`, so that's why I have so many `application - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'` logs.

I've replaced `def` with `val`

```
override val fakeApplication(): Application =
        new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
          .overrides(bind[EmailService].to(classOf[EmailServiceStub]))
          .build()
```

And it works fine.